# Does every non-commutative ring have the same numbers of left ideals and right ideals?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

We know that a non-commutative ring may have different numbers of left ideals and two-sided ideals. For example, a matrix ring over a field has only 2 two-sided ideals but it have some non-trivial left ideals. My question is about the number of left ideals and right ideals. Does every non-commutative ring have the same numbers of left ideals and right ideals?

Comment: What about the ring of upper triangular matrices?

Comment: Crossposted: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/109510/does-every-non-commutative-ring-have-the-same-numbers-of-left-ideals-and-right-id

Comment: @N.S. that ring is isomorphic to its opposite ring, so it has the same number of left and right ideals.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For another example, see the skew polynomial ring constructed in this solution: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146406/29335

Given a field endomorphism $\rho: F\rightarrow F$ such that $[F:\rho(F)]\geq 2$, it produces a ring with exactly three left ideals and at least four right ideals.

Answer (score 3):

Consider the subring $R$ of the matrix ring $M_2(\mathbb R)$ of all matrices of the form $\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\0&c\end{pmatrix}$ with $a\in\mathbb Q$, and $b$, $c\in\mathbb R$.