# Length of a ring? Lenth of a (right or left) ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

I have seen the concept of length being applied to rings. What is exactly mean by that? What does length mean in a statement like "the composition length of RR is 2, but the composition length of RR is n+1>2."?
Try to explain it in a simple fashion, please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @A.P Here you have the link is this very same forum: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/146323/on-the-length-of-a-ring/146406#146406

Comment: Then you are looking as the length of a ring $R$ as an $R$-module. Have a look at the relevant [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Length_of_a_module).

Comment: @A.P Thanks. Could you exemplify it on this paragraph from my link? Take a field endomorphism σ:F→F such that [F:σ(F)]=n>1. Form the skew polynomial ring F[x;σ]. This means you are using a noncommutative polynomial arithmetic, where xa=σ(a)x for all a∈F. Let R=F[x;σ]/(x2). The image of x in the quotient will be denoted byx¯¯¯.
Verify that Rx=Fx¯¯¯ is a minimal and maximal left ideal of R, and also a maximal right ideal. A a right R module it is semisimple with composition length n. 
 The composition length of RR is 2, but the composition length of RR is n+1>2.

Comment: It means that $Rx$ is the only left ideal of $R$, so the maximal chain of left $R$ modules contained in $R$ is $Rx \subset R$ which has length $2$ (or actually $1$, because usually one starts counting chains from $0$). On the other hand, $Rx$ maximal but not minimal as a right $R$-module, so there is a chain of length at least $3$ of right $R$-modules contained in $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $R$ be a ring. The length of a left (or right) $R$-module $M$ is the maximum length $n$ of a chain of left (or right) $R$-modules
$$
M_0 \subsetneq M_1 \subsetneq \dotsb \subsetneq M_n = M
$$
if it exists, otherwise it is said to be infinite. The length of $R$ is its length as a left (or right) $R$-module.

Note that the only module of length $0$ is the zero module, because it is contained in every other module. Furthermore, it can be shown that a module (or ring) has finite length if and only if it is both Noetherian and Artinian.

This implies that this notion of length is of limited use for commutative rings, because a commutative Noetherian ring is Artinian if and only if all of its prime ideals are maximal. In particular, every integral domain that is not a field has infinite length, because its $0$ ideal is prime. For example, if $n \in \Bbb{Z}$ is different from $0$ or $\pm 1$, then
$$
\Bbb{Z} \supsetneq (n) \supsetneq (n^2) \supsetneq (n^3) \supsetneq \dotsb
$$

Finally, note that the lengths of a ring seen as a left or right module can differ, even if they are both finite. You can find an example in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/146406/65389) (that you linked to already).

Comment: "In particular no integral domain can have finite length." I think a field is an integral domain with finite length, for example $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @awllower I was taught to exclude fields from the definition of integral domain, although the relevant Wikipedia page seems to disagree with me. Anyway, "if and only if all of its prime ideals are maximal" implies that fields are the only edge case.

Comment: Well, I thought an ideal is prime (resp. maximal) if and only if the corresponding quotient is an integral domain (resp. field). If a field is not an integral domain, then this seems weird. In any case, it is only a matter of terminology i think.